# Match pam file lines

Tags: regex, pcre

I would like to parse pam files with the following two examples and look for deny configuration.

```
auth    required     pam_faillock.so authsucc deny=4 even_deny_root unlock_time=1200
auth    required     pam_faillock.so authsucc even_deny_root unlock_time=1200
```

The pattern should match both lines:

1 Line Match should return group1 "deny=4" and group2 "4"

2 Line Match should return empty group1 and empty group2

```
(^auth\s+required\s+pam_faillock\.so).*?(?(1) (deny\=(\d+))|(.*))
```

Comment: That is not quite clear. Try `^(?|.*?(deny=(\d*))|()())`. Or, if the beginning should be considered, try `^auth\s+required\s+pam_faillock\.so\s(?|.*?(deny=(\d*))|()())?`

Comment: `(?(1)`..true case..`|`..false case..`)` is a conditional, because group1 is not optional will never look the false case, also in the first line dedny=4 is group 2 and 4 group 3

Comment: maybe you wanted a branch reset group `(?|`..`|`..`)`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Great thanks, that was exactly what I was looking for. Is it possible to fill dummy data into a third group in the last match, even if the match is not present. 
`... |()()(dummydata))`

Comment: No, it is not possible to *set* some default value via regex. It can only return what is present in the input text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
^auth\s+required\s+pam_faillock\.so\s(?|.*?(deny=(\d*))|()())?
```

*Details*:

- `^auth\s+required\s+pam_faillock\.so` - `auth required pam_faillock.so` string where the spaces can be one or many
- `\s` - a single whitespace
- `(?|.*?(deny=(\d*))|()())?` - an optional [**branch reset group**](https://www.regular-expressions.info/branchreset.html) that matches

  - `.*?(deny=(\d*))` - any zero or more chars other than line break chars as few as possible, then a Group 1 that captures `deny=` + zero or more digits that are themselves captured into Group 2
  - `|` - or
  - `()()` - Group 1 and 2 that contain empty strings.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/mGtDqH/1).